# BASH: iterating through a directory excluding certain keyword-based subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, debian-based

I'm trying to create a simple backup script that will, among other things, copy my firefox profile, excluding any cache item or folder in within that profile.

This is on my debian-based crunchbang system.

That sounds simple enough, but I'm new to bash scripting, and what I've come up with so far is so inelegant and unwieldy that I'd love to get some input.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in /home/my_name/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/*
do
echo "$f level 1"

if [[ "$f" != "Cache" ]]
then
    if [ -d $f ]
    then
        for g in $f/?
        do
           echo "$g level 2"
            for h in $g/?
            do
            echo "$h level 3"
                for i in $h/?
                do
                echo "$i level 4"
                for j in $i/?
                do
                echo "$j level 5"
                done
            done
        done
    done 
    fi
fi
done
```

The echo are there, you may have guessed, for error checking. These are to be replaced by cp statements.

One problem I see is that this is not flexible enough: if there are directories further than 5 down, they won't be included. If I extend the script to include them, I just move the problem one step over.

Another problem is one I see in the output of the script currently:

```
/home/my_name/.mozilla/firefox/gibberish.default/OfflineCache/?/?/? level 4
```

I don't know why this line shows up, but I do believe it should not.

So... any hints to help me on my way?

Comment: The technique you want to be looking for is `recursion`

Answer (score 2):

This job is best left to [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

```
rsync -avh --progress --exclude='*Cache/' ~/.mozilla/firefox/ /path/to/your/backup/location/
```

Comment: This looks like it could be the ticket for me, but I tried running it and have one (big) problem: it is still copying cache folders. Inside the ?.default folder, there are about 3 profile folders of the kind: OfflineCache, startupCache, ...

Comment: @Zaan: you have to either specify multiple `--exclude=` options, or find a wildcard pattern that matches all your folder names (`--exclude='*Cache/'`). The posted code in your question only filtered `"Cache"`, so I made the rsync command behave the same way

Answer (score 1):

The standard tool to recurse a directory structure is `find`.

```
find /home/my_name/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/* -name Cache -prune -o -type f -exec echo cp {} dest \;
```

Take out the `echo` once you see something you like. You may want to google for additional examples, perhaps with `xargs`.  If your `cp` has a `-t` option, also have a look at `\+` in the `find -exec` documentation.

Comment: This finds files named `Cache`. It does not exclude directories with name `Cache` (what the OP asked)

Comment: Thanks for the note, added the missing `-prune`.